# How do I compare two characters in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to compare two characters. Something like this:

```
if ('a' > 'b')
```

However, the above code is comparing two strings.

How do I do this in Dart?

Answer (score 4):

Dart doesn't have a 'char' or 'character' type. You can get the UTF-16 character code from any point in a string, and compare that.

Use `codeUnitAt` to get the actual character code from a string.

```
if ('a'.codeUnitAt(0) > 'b'.codeUnitAt(0))
```

See the `codeUnitAt` docs: https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/String.html#codeUnitAt

Comment: Ideally there should be a String comparison method in the intl package. So it can handle other languages with umlauts, accents, etc.

Answer (score 3):

`String` in Dart implements the `Comparable` interface. You can use `compareTo` to compare them.

```
String a = 'a';
String b = 'b';
String c = 'a';

print('value: ${a.compareTo(b)}');     // prints "value: -1"
print('value: ${a.compareTo(c)}');     // prints "value: 0"
print('value: ${b.compareTo(a)}');     // prints "value: 1"
```